# How to get a black status bar on an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xib, statusbar

I want to use a black status bar for my iPhone app. I have selected black status bar on all of my .xibs but I still can't get it to be black. Is this an issue that anyone else has seen or knows how to remedy?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

1. Open the **"info.plist"** file .
2. Add a new row.
3. Select **"Status bar style"** as the *key*.
4. Select **"Opaque black style"** as the *value*.

**EDIT:** The comment by @codrut below to choose the value:
*If you go far to the right, there's a button that brings you a drop down with the possible options.*

Comment: Well I reached to Status bar style myself but wouldn't ever have figured out to write 'Opaque black style' as the value. Thanks for saving...

Comment: @Ahmed if you go far to the right, there's a button that brings you a drop down with the possible options

Answer (score 15):

The status bar in the nib files is there as an indication, just to simulate the real interface.
What you need to do is:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
```

and in the plist change the Status Bar Style (UIStatusBarStyle) to Black opaque (UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque) (or whatever you want).

Comment: info.plist more better on application start.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following in the info.plist file

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will help anyone else, but in our app we ran into an issue where the only way we could get it to use the black style was if we set it to the default style:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
```

Might be worth giving that a try if BlackOpaque isn't working for you.

Answer (score 1):

### Try this simple method....

1.For single `viewController`

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
```

2.For whole application

```
info.plist
      ----> Status Bar Style
                  --->UIStatusBarStyle to UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque
```