# Status bar when hidden navigation bar in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I build app using UINavigationController is root view, i have issue hide navigation bar, when i hide navigation bar `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;`  status bar translucent not like status bar iOS 6 version like app [Apple Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id375380948?mt=8)

[image]

How to fix it?

PS: I use `UIBarPositionTopAttached` to UIStatusBar like iOS 6

Comment: So what kind of fix you want? Do you want to hide it?

Comment: No, i want status bar like status iOS 6 version not translucent

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a black status bar on an iPhone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792376/how-to-get-a-black-status-bar-on-an-iphone-app)

Answer (score 0):

1.Add this line in your `viewDidLoad` to get default `iOS6` style..

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
```

If you need default syle in whole app means try this.

```
info.plist
      ----> Status Bar Style
                  --->UIStatusBarStyle to UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque
```

2.Add following method to adjust status bar height in `iOS7`..

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 7) {
        CGRect windowFrame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
        windowFrame.origin.y+=20.0;
        windowFrame.size.height-= 20.0;
        self.view.frame = windowFrame;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }
}
```

Comment: I use UIBarPositionTopAttached to statusbar like iOS 6 version.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly set status bar black opaque through plist add this key in .plist file

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque</string>
```

Thanks.